# Basic HTML progress bar implementation for REST call

Tags: javascript, html, rest, file-upload

I want to implement a progress bar or spinner for a upload file REST request till it finishes. My HTML code looks like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/services/rest/fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <b>Upload Supported Files:</b>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am able to upload the file properly once started, but I must stay on the same page until the upload finishes. I want to implement a "Please wait..." kind of popup message or progress bar from start till the POST request finishes. How can I achieve this with minimal use of libraries.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whoever downvotes, kindly explain the reason in comments section as it affects others reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **[link](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/)** describe how to implement a progress bar..

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

        // Upload progress
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                //Do something with upload progress
                console.log(percentComplete);
            }
       }, false);

       // Download progress
       xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
           if (evt.lengthComputable) {
               var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
               // Do something with download progress
               console.log(percentComplete);
           }
       }, false);

       return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/",
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
        // Do something success-ish
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `ajaxForm`.

You need to include this script for `ajaxForm`

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

[`ajaxForm` Documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

```
$(function() {

    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}); 

 <form action="http://localhost:8080/services/rest/fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <b>Upload Supported Files:</b>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```